# WPF: Parent which would display a specific child depending on input value

Tags: c#, wpf

As far as I understand, usual `Visibility={Binding SomeValue, Converter={…}}` still keeps node in visual and logical tree even if it’s invisible. But what if I want to remove it completely and at the same time keep syntax light?

Right now, I’ve made a class called `Switch` allowing me to do stuff like that:

```
<Switch Value="{Binding Status}">
    <TextBlock Switch.When="{x:Static Status.NotFound}" Text="Not found" />
    <Button Switch.When="{x:Static Status.ConnectionError}" Text="Connection error. Try again?" />
    <Grid Switch.When="{x:Static Status.Loaded}">…</Grid>
</Switch>
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/gro-ove/3de0d9fe36891e8463e8197f56cd0274) is a source code of that `Switch` thing.

I like how it looks and works, but sometimes some errors occur. For instance, while removing visual child from its previous location, rarely, but `System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot modify the logical children for this node at this time because a tree walk is in progress.` might happen. Cases like this are solvable, but the whole thing with them makes me think I’m doing something very wrong. What could it be? Maybe the whole idea is just not compatible with WPF at all? Or maybe I’m just missing something (like that thing that I have to override `IEnumerator LogicalChildren { get; }` to make it work properly)?

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is probably that you're trying to reparent the child controls the right way. Bad idea! They're just arbitrary content; don't treat them as controls. The actual reparenting in my code is done by hidden `ContentPresenter` magic in the template. All our control class code does is just sling them around like potatoes.

Here's a working version of the control that shouldn't give you any backtalk. But note that I had trouble comparing boxed enum values to each other. I'm interested in how you solved that problem.

Switch.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace SwitchTestProject
{
    [ContentProperty("Items")]
    public class Switch : Control
    {
        public Switch()
        {
            Items = new List<DependencyObject>();
        }

        static Switch()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Switch), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Switch)));
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            OnValueChanged(null);
        }

        #region Switch.When Attached Property
        public static Object GetWhen(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Object)obj.GetValue(WhenProperty);
        }

        public static void SetWhen(DependencyObject obj, Object value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(WhenProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty WhenProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("When", typeof(Object), typeof(Switch),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));
        #endregion Switch.When Attached Property

        #region Content Property
        public Object Content
        {
            get { return (Object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
            protected set { SetValue(ContentPropertyKey, value); }
        }

        internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ContentPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(Content), typeof(Object), typeof(Switch),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = ContentPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
        #endregion Content Property

        #region Value Property
        public Object Value
        {
            get { return (Object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Value), typeof(Object), typeof(Switch),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, Value_PropertyChanged));

        protected static void Value_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (d as Switch).OnValueChanged(e.OldValue);
        }

        private void OnValueChanged(object oldValue)
        {
            if (Value is IComparable)
            {
                //  Boxed value types have to be a special case. 
                //  Unless I jumped to an unwarranted conclusion about == not working. 

                var icompval = Value as IComparable;

                foreach (var item in Items)
                {
                    var icompwhen = GetWhen(item) as IComparable;

                    if (icompwhen != null && icompval.CompareTo(icompwhen) == 0)
                    {
                        Content = item;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Content = Items.FirstOrDefault(item => GetWhen(item) == Value);
            }
        }
        #endregion Value Property

        #region Items Property
        public List<DependencyObject> Items
        {
            get { return (List<DependencyObject>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            protected set { SetValue(ItemsPropertyKey, value); }
        }

        internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ItemsPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(Items), typeof(List<DependencyObject>), typeof(Switch),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = ItemsPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
        #endregion Items Property
    }
}
```

App.xaml or Themes\Generic.xaml

You could do a lot more with styling the parent here.

```
<Style TargetType="local:Switch">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Switch">
                <ContentPresenter
                    />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<local:Switch
    Value="{Binding Status}"
    >
    <TextBlock 
        local:Switch.When="{x:Static local:Status.NotFound}"
        >This is a test</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock 
        local:Switch.When="{x:Static local:Status.ConnectionError}"
        >There was an error in the connection</TextBlock>
</local:Switch>
```

## Pure XAML alternative

The bug in your `Switch` control is probably fixable, but this will work reliably without any nonsense (other than all the verbosity).

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="NotFound">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Not found" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="ConnectionError">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Connection error. Try again?" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Loaded">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Ellipse
                                    Height="32"
                                    Width="32"
                                    Fill="DeepSkyBlue"
                                    />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

We set the content using `DataTemplates` rather than setting the `Content` property directly because if we use the latter method, only one instance of each child control will ever exist, so we wouldn't be able to factor the style out as a resource and reuse it.

And because templating is the canonical way to create new controls in XAML.

Comment: Thank you, works great! And binding, and visual initialization, everything appears to happen only when needed.

For now, I compare values in [a very primitive way](https://gist.github.com/gro-ove/87867496fede43818a490808d608f688#file-converterhelper-cs-L65), but it didn’t let me down yet. Although, of course, I’m planning to fix it later (right now, `Value` binds to typed variable, but `When` — from XAML — are just strings usually, that’s why this piece looks like that).

Comment: @SurfinBird Cool. How were you comparing the enum values?

Comment: I reference them as `{x:Static EnumType.EnumValue}` in XAML (to avoid confusion while refactoring), and there are no flag enums there (yet?), so simple Equals usually works just fine…